# Finitely presentable objects in the categories of algebras of $\infty$-algebraic theories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, monads, higher-algebra

*By default, all terms are understood in the infinity sense (“category” means “$(\infty, 1)$-category”, etc.).*

An object $A$ in a category is said to be finitely presentable (or compact) if the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -)$ preserves filtered colimits.

In the (classical) $1$-truncated world, the following fact is well known: in the category of algebras of algebraic theories (aka: categories of algebras over monads of finite rank on $\mathrm{Set}$), finitely presentable objects are exactly objects having a finite presentation (given by finite generators and relations).

Is there a known generalization of this statement to the non-truncated case?

Here's what I know about it:

1. Finitely presentable objects in $\infty\text{-}\mathrm{Groupoid}$ are exactly retracts of $\infty$-groupoids given by a finite generators and relations (see Wall's finiteness obstruction)
2. I think that the forgetful functor will also preserve filtered colimits (but I haven't found a reference for this yet) and therefore the free one will preserve finitely presentable objects.

So,

> Is it true that every finitely presentable object in a (finitary) algebraic category is a coequalizer of finitely generated free objects?

I see a discussion of (non-truncated) monads and algebraic categories in

- [Higher Algebra](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf)
- [Algebraic Theories and (Infinity,1)-Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3243)
- [Higher Lawvere theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02991v1)

but I haven’t noticed an answer to my question anywhere yet.

Comment: What is your definition of "free" objects? Let's say, the $\infty$-category of anima (you wrote $\infty$-groupoids, but they are *models* of homotopy types, i.e. anima). What are free objects in your mind?

Comment: @Z.M I'm not talking about the concept of a free object in a category. Free objects are those that are in the image of the free functor (from the monadic adjunction). For the $\rm{id}$ monad on $\infty$-groupoid, the category of algebras will be $\infty$-groupoids themselves and in this case all objects are free (i.e., the same as for sets).

Comment: @Z.M Why do you say that infinity-groupoids are models of anima? In my usual terminology, these two words are just synonyms. But, for example, Kan complexes are a model (of infinity-groupoids / anime).

For example, [this nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinity-groupoid) is full of evidence of the prevalence of such terminology . Every time I came across the word “infinity-groupoid” it meant the invariant concept itself, and not some kind of model (just like with other $(\infty, n)$-categories).

Comment: Your question is answered in the negative by your first point: a coequalizer of fg free objects has a finite presentation, but not every compact object has a finite presentation. It is true in general that the compact objects will be retracts of those having a finite presentation (the latter is of course what "finitely presentable" should refer to...), because Ind(C)^ω is the idempotent completion of C.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Why? In the first example, all objects are free, co-equalizers are not even needed. Or do you mean there are other examples (with meaningful algebraic structure) where what you say happens?

Comment: No, I mean it already happens in anima (but of course it will also happen in many other examples). All anima are free but not all are finitely generated.

Comment: @MarcHoyois By “finitely generated free object” I meant, of course, the image of compact anima under the action of the free functor (just like in the 1-situation). Therefore, in the case of anima, everything is tautological.

Comment: I see, but for other Lawvere theories there is no reason to expect a positive answer: you will need more general finite colimits as well as retracts, as explained in Tim Campion's answer. If I may, I would suggest adjusting your terminology, since compact objects are not finitely generated/presented in any sense.

Comment: Could you recommend a link, if one exists? (about the presentation of compact $\infty$-algebraic objects by colimits of free ones)

Comment: "Finitely presentable object" and "compact object" are just synonymous terms, as far as I know. See on [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object#FinitelyPresentableObject), for example, among many other texts. Also, Lurie writes about this in Remark 5.3.4.4 (HTT).

Comment: I'm not sure that's exactly what you want, but HTT 5.3.5.11(2) and 5.4.2.4 imply that all compact objects are in the closure under finite colimits and retracts of any generating set of compact objects. Finitely presentable literally means "has a finite presentation", and unlike in 1-category theory this is not equivalent to being compact. Lurie also makes this distinction, see for instance HA Def. 7.2.4.26.

Answer (score 1):

No, this fails even for the infinity category of spaces, where "free" means "discrete". A coequalizer of free spaces is a wedge of circles, so for example $S^2$ is not of this form.

What is true is that every compact object is a retract of a $\Delta_{\leq n}^{op}$-indexed colimit of free objects, where $\Delta_{\leq n}$ is a finite full subcategory of the simplex category. Equivalently, it's in the closure of the free objects under pushouts and retracts. Note that idempotent splitting is a non-finite colimit infinity categorically. This is again illustrated in Spaces by the Wall finiteness obstruction.

Comment: I don't yet understand in what sense your first paragraph is an example of the setting of my question. I am talking about finitary monads on the category of $\infty$-groupoids.  A monad whose category of algebras are themselves $\infty$-groupoids, is the identity monad. And in this case, just all objects are free, aren’t they?

Comment: On the other hand, a description of finite presentable objects as retracts of simplicial colimits of finitely generated discrete free objects would also be useful to me. Could you suggest a reference to this?